# How to mosaic multiple rasters and keep their attribute tables in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, arcgis-10.6

I have multiple rasters and I would like to mosaic together. For each raster, I have created an attribute table that contains one additional column of text codes. I have not been able to keep the associated information from the attribute tables when mosaicing. I have tried using the 'Mosaic to New Raster' tool and tried building a raster dataset within a geodatabase.

I use arcGIS 10.6 but I also have ArcGIS Pro 2.5

Comment: Are the values and tables of all rasters identical? If so you should be able to mosaic to new raster, build your attribute table then join your old attribute table with Join Field https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000065000000

Comment: I can't join because the raster has no attribute table. When I build a new one with build attribute raster table tool there is no field that can join with the old rasters. That's the problem..

Comment: A new raster attribute table has a 'value' field and a cell count at the bare minimum, the 'value' between the original and mosaiced raster should be the same as that is the cell value the table looks up to.

Comment: They are the same. A tought ArcGIS generate a new pixel values after build raster attribute table tool.. but your right. Thank you for helping.

Comment: The Build Raster Attribute table keeps the values of the raster and creates a simple dbf table matching all the values that exist in the specified raster. You can only create RATs for integer type rasters: Byte, Short and Long; floating point rasters would have too many values and would be 1 row for every pixel, the maximum file size for a DBF is 2GiB which you'd hit fairly quickly if you could build RAT on a float raster. If you're having difficulty assigning by joining you could use Explorer (or Explorer replacement) to copy the .dbf file and rename it to match the mosaiced raster base name.